# android : listening to keypress from background

Tags: android, events, background

I read many answers on this topic and this is what i have understood

It is not possible to get any hardkey (home,menu,back,etsc ) press events from a service. It is not delivered to any service

For key camera button and media control broadcast events are sent if these applications are not already in the foreground.

So i need to conclude that it is not possible to launch an app by pressing a hardkey or a combination of hardkeys ie ( like home key 2 times or menu key and then back key ) ?

If this is the case how is samsung launching Vlingo when home key is pressed 2 times. 
How this functionality is added to samsung galaxy

thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Service Can not get the KeyEvent.

Sumsung can do it directly with the system rom. But we can not.

Comment: Any pointers on how its actually done. Its not for me to go ahead and try :) , just out of curiosity. Are they modifying the android default behaviour.